# how can i access mongodb document's array? (mongodb, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi i have some problems with mongodb.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  url: String,
  images: Array
});

const categoriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  company: companySchema,
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('categories', categoriesSchema);
```

above of code is model

```js
    app.post('/addCompanyinfo', function (req, res){
        var news = new Categories();
        news.company[name]= req.body.company;  <--- here!
        news.save(function (err) {
            if(err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.json({result: 0});
                return;
            }
            res.json({result: 1})
        })
    })
```

and this is router code. and i want to access 
categoriesSchema-> company (companySchema)-> name.

how can i access company schema's 'name' ??

your help will be a big lucky in future to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post your data in json format and use `bodyParser.json()` middleware in your `app.js`, and your backend code can be this:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var news = new Categories(req.body); // create record directly with the json data
  console.log(req.body.company.name);  //just access it directly

  news.save(function (err) {
      if(err) {
          console.error(err);
          res.json({result: 0});
          return;
      }
      res.json({result: 1});
  });
});
```

and json format can be this:

```
{
  "company": {
      "name": "test company name",
      "url": "http://test.com",
      "image": []
  },
  "name": "test name"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Object for `Company` to assign its properties

```
var news = new Categories();
var company = new Company();
news.company = company;

news.name = 'test category'  
company.name = 'test company';

console.log(company);
```

console log

```
{ name: 'test category',
  company: { _id: 5a61629b74f8df0bd73142ba, images: [] },
  _id: 5a61629b74f8df0bd73142b9 }


{ name: 'test company', _id: 5a61629b74f8df0bd73142ba, images: [] }
```